# Division algorithm for a floating poting

Tags: c, algorithm, division

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//  divisionAlg -- This will take the incoming value and "asciify" each byte according to
//                 a character lookup table
//
//  Parameters:
//      unsigned int value -- the value to be asciified
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void divisionAlg(unsigned int value);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])        // Always remember to pass an argument while executing
{
 divisionAlg(45);
}

void divisionAlg(unsigned int value)
{
    int MAX_REM=2;
    int MAX_BASE=10;
    const char *charTable = {"0123456789ABCDEF"};  // lookup table for converting remainders
    char rembuf[MAX_REM + 1];   // holds remainder(s) and provision null at the end
    int  index;                 // 
    int  i;                     // loop variable

    unsigned int rem;           // remainder
    unsigned int base;          // we'll be using base 10 
    ssize_t numWritten;         // holds number of bytes written from write() system call

    base = 10;

    // validate base
    if (base < 2 || base > MAX_BASE)
        err_sys("oops, the base is wrong");

    // For some reason, every time this method is called after the initial call, rembuf
    // is magically filled with a bunch of garbage; this just sets everything to null.
    // NOTE: memset() wasn't working either, so I have to use a stupid for-loop
    for (i=0; i<MAX_REM; i++)
        rembuf[i] = '\0';

    rembuf[MAX_REM] = 0;    // set last element to zero
    index = MAX_REM;        // start at the end of rembuf when adding in the remainders

    do
    {
        // calculate remainder and divide valueBuff by the base
        rem = value % base;
        value /= base;

        // convert remainder into ASCII value via lookup table and store in buffer
        index--;
        rembuf[index] = charTable[rem];

    } while (value != 0);

    // display value
    if ((numWritten = write(STDOUT_FILENO, rembuf, MAX_REM + 1)) == -1)
        err_sys("something went wrong with the write");

} // end of divisionAlg()
```

I'm trying to make a division algorithm and I have no Idea why is not working, help pls!

This "division alg" is supossed to take the incoming value and "asciify" each byte according to a character lookup table

Comment: How is it not working - blows up, gives wrong output?

Comment: Unrelatedly: C and C++, unlike almost every other language, do not guarantee that variables are initialized to 0 or any other default value - so whenever it matters, you have to do it yourself. (And memset does work, make sure you are calling it correctly)

Comment: I'm convinced that memset will work.  You sure you're calling it correctly?

Comment: Can you please explain me how to call memset in this context?

Comment: `memset(rebuf, '\0', MAX_REM+1)` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think this is why:

You start by initializing the whole array (of length MAX_REM+1, e.g. 0 to MAX_REM are valid indexes) to nulls (0x00). So rembuf looks like this (0x00 being ascii null):

'0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', ... '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00'

Now, we insert values into rembuf by doing this:

```
index = MAX_REM;
index--;
rembuf[index] = charTable[rem];
```

So by the end of the loop we might have something like this if we run your algorithm on 12:

'0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', ... '0x00', '1', '2', '0x00'

Now to print you do this:

```
if ((numWritten = write(STDOUT_FILENO, rembuf, MAX_REM + 1)) == -1)
```

The problem is that you pass it rembuf. When it reads from rembuf it sees 0x00 immediately and decides 'this string is empty, I have nothing to do'. What you should actually be doing is passing it a pointer to where your number begins - where the '1' is in memory. (EDIT: As the comment says, `write()` writes as many bytes as you tell it to and doesn't stop on nulls, so this isn't the reason)

EDIT: While you're at it, MAX_REM should be much larger (it needs to be 10 for the case of holding 2^32 as a string - 20 for 2^64)

Comment: "The problem is that you pass it rembuf. When it reads from rembuf it sees 0x00 immediately and decides 'this string is empty, I have nothing to do'." -- This part isn't quite right. `write()` doesn't stop when it sees NULs.

Comment: You are correct - it writes as many bytes as you tell it to. I think I need to know what is not working about the algorithm (doesn't produce right values, doesn't write anything visible, doesn't write at all, crashes, overflows...) to guess again :)